# Windows Server 2012 with ASP.NET MVC application stops working (ESENT errors)

Tags: sql-server, iis, model-view-controller, hyper-v, esent

The solution is an ASP.NET MVC application using E/F hosted in IIS on a Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard VM hosted in a Hyper-V environment. The same VM is running SQL Server 2012.

The hosting environment is hosting 30 other solutions and there is plenty of free disk space and no known disk problems with hosting environment or VM (chkdsk and sfc has been run on VM and did not report any problems).

The problem is that the solution/server stops working for short periods of 5-1o minutes and every time we see event ID 508/533 from ESENT and a message about writing to "C:\Windows\system32\LogFiles\Sum".

A similar message has been seen with sqlsvr but this was solved by giving everyone all rights to C:\Windows\system32\LogFiles\Sum.

When the problem persists, it affects the whole VM and sometimes it is no even possible to connect via remote desktop.

We have seen a high number of open SQL Server connections when the problems occurs and prior to introducing caching for a specific Web API method we were actually able to empty the SQL Server connection pool. Just in case we have changed the connection pool from 100 to 200 connections even though we have not seen this particular problem since we introduced the cache.

All DbContext instances are disposed by "using", an ApiController.Dispose override or a Controller.Dispose override and only one SqlConnection are used (for the logging system).

I suspect the problem to be outside the solution and that the high number of SQL Server connections are related to the fact that SQL Server is unable to write to the disk.

Below is some Windows Event Log excerpts for three recent "break downs" with some additional info about the number of web request prior to the problem and after the server has automatically recovered.

Any suggestions?

> web requests during the 10 minutes right before the problem: 1399
>   web requests during the first 10 minutes after the server has recovered: 1630

18-03-2015 20:07:20 833 MSSQLSERVER
SQL Server has encountered 1 occurrence(s) of I/O requests taking longer than 15 seconds to complete on file [C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Xxx.mdf] in database [Xxx] (5).  The OS file handle is 0x0000000000000A7C.  The offset of the latest long I/O is: 0x000003e104e000

18-03-2015 20:07:40 833 MSSQLSERVER
SQL Server has encountered 1 occurrence(s) of I/O requests taking longer than 15 seconds to complete on file [C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Xxx_log.ldf] in database [Xxx] (5).  The OS file handle is 0x0000000000000A8C.  The offset of the latest long I/O is: 0x0000007f203000

18-03-2015 20:08:16 533 ESENT
svchost (1740) A request to write to the file "C:\Windows\system32\LogFiles\Sum\Svc.log" at offset 1806336 (0x00000000001b9000) for 4096 (0x00001000) bytes has not completed for 36 second(s). This problem is likely due to faulty hardware. Please contact your hardware vendor for further assistance diagnosing the problem.

18-03-2015 20:17:14 508 ESENT
svchost (1740) A request to write to the file "C:\Windows\system32\LogFiles\Sum\Svc.log" at offset 1806336 (0x00000000001b9000) for 4096 (0x00001000) bytes succeeded, but took an abnormally long time (36 seconds) to be serviced by the OS. This problem is likely due to faulty hardware. Please contact your hardware vendor for further assistance diagnosing the problem.

> web requests during the 10 minutes right before the problem: 696
>   web requests during the first 10 minutes after the server has recovered: 614

19-03-2015 01:17:19 533 ESENT
svchost (1740) A request to write to the file "C:\Windows\system32\LogFiles\Sum\Svc.log" at offset 3067904 (0x00000000002ed000) for 4096 (0x00001000) bytes has not completed for 36 second(s). This problem is likely due to faulty hardware. Please contact your hardware vendor for further assistance diagnosing the problem.

19-03-2015 01:33:02 508 ESENT
svchost (1740) A request to write to the file "C:\Windows\system32\LogFiles\Sum\Svc.log" at offset 3067904 (0x00000000002ed000) for 4096 (0x00001000) bytes succeeded, but took an abnormally long time (983 seconds) to be serviced by the OS. This problem is likely due to faulty hardware. Please contact your hardware vendor for further assistance diagnosing the problem.

19-03-2015 01:33:03 833 MSSQLSERVER
SQL Server has encountered 5 occurrence(s) of I/O requests taking longer than 15 seconds to complete on file [C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Xxx_log.ldf] in database [Xxx] (5).  The OS file handle is 0x0000000000000A8C.  The offset of the latest long I/O is: 0x000000a389d000

> web requests during the 10 minutes right before the problem: 555
>   web requests during the first 10 minutes after the server has recovered: 784

19-03-2015 03:33:51 833 MSSQLSERVER
SQL Server has encountered 1 occurrence(s) of I/O requests taking longer than 15 seconds to complete on file [C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\Xxx_log.ldf] in database [Xxx] (5).  The OS file handle is 0x0000000000000A8C.  The offset of the latest long I/O is: 0x000000aa95f000

19-03-2015 03:40:48 533 ESENT
svchost (1740) A request to write to the file "C:\Windows\system32\LogFiles\Sum\Svc.log" at offset 3846144 (0x00000000003ab000) for 4096 (0x00001000) bytes has not completed for 36 second(s). This problem is likely due to faulty hardware. Please contact your hardware vendor for further assistance diagnosing the problem.

19-03-2015 03:40:48 833 MSSQLSERVER
SQL Server has encountered 1 occurrence(s) of I/O requests taking longer than 15 seconds to complete on file [C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\MSDBLog.ldf] in database [msdb] (4).  The OS file handle is 0x0000000000000A90.  The offset of the latest long I/O is: 0x00000000108000

19-03-2015 03:40:49 508 ESENT
svchost (1740) A request to write to the file "C:\Windows\system32\LogFiles\Sum\Svc.log" at offset 3846144 (0x00000000003ab000) for 4096 (0x00001000) bytes succeeded, but took an abnormally long time (36 seconds) to be serviced by the OS. This problem is likely due to faulty hardware. Please contact your hardware vendor for further assistance diagnosing the problem.

19-03-2015 03:40:49 17894 MSSQLSERVER
Dispatcher (0x1a88) from dispatcher pool 'XE Engine main dispatcher pool' Worker 0x00000000F03B8160 appears to be non-yielding on Node 0. Approx CPU Used: kernel 0 ms, user 0 ms, Interval: 336140.

Answer (score 1):

Disk I/O problems was my initial thought but the "funny" thing is that it actually never has happened during peak hours and that the server during peak hours is not stressed on CPU or disk I/O.

I cannot find any VM disk errors. I have no access to the hosting environment but I am told that there are no disk problems. The hosting environment is performing VM backups and if this is the problem, there is nothing to do about it, as it is required. I might try to have the VM moved to another disk but I do not know if this is possible.

Currently we have set up some detailed disk I/O monitoring on the VM and hopefully this will give us some information about the problem but I rather doubt it.

Maybe the VM is just "sick" and the next step might be to create a new one from scratch…

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your disk is just plain overloaded, since I/Os are taking so long. Ideally they should take around 10 milliseconds. Instead, they're taking over 1000x that long.

Since you're running in a VM, though, tracking down the problem can be a bit more tricky. Is it due to the I/O load in the virtual machine, or on the host? Your VM disk may be shared with other I/O load of the host.

Can you move the database to a different volume in the VM, hosted on a different physical spindle of the host?

Another possibility is that the underlying storage is going bad, and the I/Os are being retried by the underlying hardware.

-martin